# Use a Hibernate Session with dedicated datasource connection per Spring Security session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session

Is it possible to change the database authentication of a `Hibernate Session`  (or create a new one) at runtime, and link it to the current logged-in web-user?

E.g. when a specific `Spring Security`-managed user logs in, reconnect it with a different database role, and use that connection throughout the lifetime of the http session for that user?

Comment: You can do stuff but it is Database dependent. Which database?

Comment: It's PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

The hibernate session and the http session are not related, I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding your question. If you were to store the user details such as the role in the http session you will have this problem as you describe where the role has been changed yet the user still has the old privileges because Spring Security is reading the user details from the session not the database. However, if you only were to store the user ID and not keep any information about the user in the http session you wont have refresh issues. Usually you don't even store the user in the session because you can just access the principal in Spring.
Hibernate sessions are created and closed per a transaction. You should use transactions so the database handles all concurrency issues for you and you don't have to worry about if for instance the users password was getting changed whilst some other transaction was going to use it.

Typically you shouldn't store anything which is in a database in the Http session. Was this what you were after?

**Edit** Still a little unclear what you are asking, I will have a guess. Do you want to create new database credentials for your database, with privileges like you would in mysql workbench or something, and then use a database connection with those credentials for every Http session when a user logins?

There is no mechanism in Spring to do this as this would be database dependent. Its not recommended to create a database connection per Http session, as you will lose your nice little connection pool optimization Hibernate and Spring provide for you. If your app has allot of users it will suffer a significant performance hit from so many connections, may even just freeze if you had many many users. And again I need to clarify you may have an open connection with the database, but you don't leave hibernate sessions open for extended periods, they are just a wrapper for talking to a database connection when you need to. Although I don't recommend you do this, and would rugby tackle you to stop you if you were in my team, I guess there are 2 ways:

Firstly you'll have to create the credentials on the command line via Java running some script probably. Then you'll need to make a session datasource, and wire that up to all your Daos. You won't be able to use any Spring's stuff like @Transactional, or @PreAuthorize ect. (although you could still use @PreAuthorize just don't use hasRole, or any functions that will talk to the wrong datasource). You will just have to do permission logic manually, and program your hibernate sessions manually.

If that wasn't good enough for you, you can just go full blown maniac, and purchase an extremely powerful server and launch a whole other 'clone' Spring Webapp for each http session which is a exactly the same except it has a different root url and the new connection configuration. Then redirect that user to their personal webapp, talk about 1st class service.

Look honestly it's a really bad idea either way, and you can literally achieve the same user experience by using Spring Security. A database connection is just a resource to be used optimally. I wouldn't give every user of a webapp their own connection, any more than I would give every employee at a company their own personal toilet. Instead I'd give them a key card for permission to share available toilets, you should rather do that.

Comment: I want a database connection with a dedicated user for each web-application user from the same account. Is that clearer?

Comment: I understand that there is no link between http and hibernate session. I want to create a hibernate session per logged-in user, which uses a dedicated database user.

Comment: You're getting closer. Instead of a database connectio per http session, would it not be better and more feasible to have a Hibernate SessionFactory per user?

Comment: You can make any component in your application session based, except for all the Spring stuff like the transaction manager, and security manager. You can still achieve dynamic behavior with those components with either session beans or data changing in a database. So you could make some session scoped sessionFactory but the sessionFactory Spring Security uses won't be able to be session based, that doesn't make logical sense, that will needs to be singleton.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is feasible to have a dedicated DB session per user. Even if technically possible an application with a large user base is not going to scale very well. An alternative approach is to configure a standard connection pool and associate the connection with a specific web application user each time it is checked out from the pool.

There is some discussion on this here (from an Oracle perspective but same principles apply regardless of RDBMS):

> Many applications use session pooling to set up a number of sessions
>   to be reused by multiple application users. Users authenticate
>   themselves to a middle-tier application, which uses a single identity
>   to log in to the database and maintains all the user connections. In
>   this model, application users are users who are authenticated to the
>   middle tier of an application, but who are not known to the database.....in 
>   these situations, the application typically connects as a single
>   database user and all actions are taken as that user. Because all user
>   sessions are created as the same user, this security model makes it
>   very difficult to achieve data separation for each user. **These
>   applications can use the CLIENT_IDENTIFIER attribute to preserve the
>   real application user identity through to the database.**

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/apdvprxy.htm#i1010372

How you might acheive this is discussed in section 8.2 of the Spring documentation at the below. Note that while this is hidden away in a section specific to Spring's Oracle extensions there is nothing in section 8.2 (unlike 8.1) that is Oracle specific (other than the Statement executed) and the general approach should be feasible with any Database simply by specifying the relevant procedure call or SQL:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/orcl.connection.html

I am not too familiar with Postgres but I guess the call you would want to make on each Connection checkout would be something like:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-set-role.html

The example given in the Spring docs uses XML config. If you are using Java config then it looks like:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class ClientIdentifierConnectionPreparer implements ConnectionPreparer
{
  @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* *.getConnection(..))", returning = "connection")
  public Connection prepare(Connection connection) throws SQLException
  {
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    String webAppUser = //;

    CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall("my postgres statement");
    cs.setString(1, webAppUser);
    cs.execute();
    cs.close();

    return connection;
  }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class SomeConfigurationClass
{

}
```