# How to run custom query in the beginning of each transaction?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, firebird, spring-transactions

I'm using Firebird database in my project, and my stored procedures in DB are using custom [context variables](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-set-context.html) that are transaction scoped.

I have to set some variables to context in the beginning of each transaction. How can I implement this without repeating code in each @Transactional annotated method?

Example:

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping({TBL_EMPLOYEE, TBL_EMP})
public class EmployeeController extends EmployeeCommonController<Employee> {
         
@GetMapping(PATH_LASTLOGIN)
    public List<UserLastLoginWrapper> getUserLastLoginWrapper(Long userid, tring appname) {
        return getService().getUserLastLoginWrapper(userid, appname);
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Transactional
public class EmployeeService{
  public List<UserLastLoginWrapper> getUserLastLoginWrapper(Long userid, String appname) {
        return ((EmployeeRepository) getRepository()).getUserLastLoginWrapper(null, userid, appname);
    }
}
```

Repository

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "Employee.getUserLastLoginWrapper", query = "select * from SP_USER_LAST_LOGIN(:userid, :appname)", resultSetMapping = UserLastLoginWrapper.USERLASTLOGINWRAPPER)
```

Most of the stored procedures are trying to get hotelrefno info from context variables, so I have to call `execute procedure SP_CTX_SET_LOGIN_INFO(:hotelrefno, :userid)` procedure in the beginning of each transaction.

Comment: Please provide some code to illustrate your question

Comment: See my answer here for an AOP based solution (answer refers to Oracle however should be relevant for an DB): https://stackoverflow.com/a/47809487/1356423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call this query after getting connection. See aspect configuration below.

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* *.getConnection(..))", returning = "connection")
public Connection prepare(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall(
                "execute procedure SP_CTX_SET_LOGIN_INFO(?,?,?,?)");
//....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a Before Aspect

```
@Aspect
public class ProdcedureAspect {

    @Before("execution(* **.*Service.*(..))")
    public void doBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) { 
       // execute procedure SP_CTX_SET_LOGIN_INFO(:hotelrefno, :userid)
    }
}
```

Read more about Spring AOP here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-api

Comment: This answer is also correct, but there might be situations that separate transaction are created in same service class methods.